# How can i access a element inside of a handlebars template?

Tags: templates, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

How can i access a element inside of a handlebars template? Im trying to access the #element-{{id}} inside the Handlebars Helper but im receiving a null on log.

[JSBin example](https://jsbin.com/qulakolehi/edit?html,console,output)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<script id="video-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each items}}
<div class="panel-heading">
<h3 class="panel-title">{{snippet.title}}</h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
{{someFunction id}}
<div id="element-{{id}}"></div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
</div>
</div>

<script>
Handlebars.registerHelper('someFunction', function(id) {
console.log(document.getElementById("element-"+id));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that i dont have the element on the DOM when the handlebar helper is called, so i used a timeout function for that...

```
setTimeout(function(){
var element = document.getElementById("element-"+id);
console.log(element);
},1000);
```

anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you concantenating the element and the id.. ?

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('someFunction', function(id) {
    console.log(document.getElementById("element-"+id));
```

Try this instead:

```
var butter = document.getElementById("butter_id");
console.log("thisid:",butter);
```

Also try removing handlebars from your function.Register your helper and function seperately and  then call  the helper variables referencing the function("getElementById or getElementByName")

```
function getElementById(name,url){  
if(!url)url = window.location.href;
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/9,"\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' +name+'(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$|)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if(!results) return null;
if(!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/9,""));
```

Then:

...your helper...

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('butter',(id) {
var element = document.getElementById("butter_id");
    console.log(document.getElementById("yourelement-",element));
```